# Dual of the space of vector valued Borel measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, real-analysis

What is the dual of the space of all vector valued Borel measures?

Comment: What kind of underlying topological space should the borel measures have? A polish space? A locally compact space? Something else?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/74875/442  for signed measures.  What do you mean with both "vector valued" and "signed" at the same time?

Comment: Assume that the space is equipped with the total variation norm.

Comment: So presumably the values are in some normed space?

Comment: @WeymonHe: You misunderstood. Your measures are maps $\mathfrak{B}(X)\to V$ for some topological space X and some vector space V. My question concerns X. Do want to impose any restrictions on X like being a polish space etc.?

Comment: Yes. To be more specific, let $\Omega \subset R^n$ and assume M is the space of all finite signed Radon measures defined on $\Omega$. What is the dual of M or M^m?

Comment: As discussed in  math.stackexchange.com/q/74875/442, it seems that it is not easy to characterize the dual space. Is there a well characterized space that contains the dual space?